# (C++) Accessing private member variables from a private base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

So my program requires the base class Media to have the members set to private as well as the constructor. I can't make them protected or public, thanks.

```
class Media
{
public:
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Media &Media)
    {
        output << Media.mId << " " << Media.mTitle << " " << Media.mYear << " "
                << Media.mRatings;
        return output;
    }
    Media(int id, string title, int year, int ratings);
//void printRating();
    friend class Movie;
private:

    int mId, mYear, mRatings;
    string mTitle;
};
Media::Media(int id, string title, int year, int ratings)
{
    mId = id;
    mTitle = title;
    mYear = year;
    mRatings = ratings;
}
class Movie: public Media
{
public:
    Movie(int id, string title, int year, string director);
    string mDirector;
};
Movie::Movie(int id, string title, int year, string director) :
        mId(id), mTitle(title), mYear(year), mDirector(director)
{
}

int main()
{

    Media *ptr[10];
    ptr[0] = new Movie(352, "Fight Club", 1999, "David Fincher");
//cout << *ptr[0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Base class members cannot be used in [initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

> In the definition of a constructor of a class, member initializer list specifies the initializers for direct and virtual base subobjects and non-static data members.

However you can call the constructor of the base class:

```
Movie::Movie(int id, string title, int year, string director) :
    Media(id, title, year, 0), // 0 or or whatever default rating value should be
    mDirector(director)
{
}
```